# HTML 5 CSS3 rendering on IE 8

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-8, version

I have very little knowledge of coding. I am trying to do research on behalf of our front-end developers. We want to redesign our portal application using CSS 3 and HTML 5. Our main aim is to have an adaptive layout to match the different browser widths our users have access to. There is also excessive usage of iframes in the portal which is why we want the app to adapt to the full browser width. Our users primarily use chrome, firefox but a handful are still using ie 8 with no scope of upgrade. I need advise on the best ways to go about creating visual design using HTML 5 and CSS3 that would render on IE 8 without breaking. Is it possible to create the application using HTML 5 and CSS 3 that would automatically switch to a simpler but efficient layout when the user opens the application in IE 8. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

modernizr.com
jquery.com

see caniuse.com for a listing of unsupported features in your IE and chromium versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HTML5 shiv. It enables the use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy IE and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet Explorer 6-9, Safari 4.x (and iPhone 3.x), and Firefox 3.x. Include this file: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/dist/html5shiv.js

with this line in your header:

`<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="your-path-here/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->`

You can also add a conditional tag to give your HTML a class when the browser is IE8 to add IE8 specific styles when you can't get CSS3 to work.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie ie9 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><html><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

By using these conditional tags, you can then overwrite a rule that doesn't work in IE8 and make it work for that browser only. For example, `.ie8 .button-style`

Something else you can do to support CSS3 elements like drop shadows, gradients, transitions, etc is to use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/). PIE makes it possible to use CSS3 in older versions of IE by including a small JS file.

`display: inline-block` is your best friend. This property will specify that if two things fit inside of their container side by side, do that, otherwise stack them vertically. If you're having a positioning/display problem, try applying inline-block. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in some older IE versions without this hack:

```
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

IE8 does support some CSS3 properties. You should check on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/). Also, for the best cross browser support use [CSS3 vendor prefixes](http://css-snippets.com/browser-prefix/).

Good luck!